# Adding class to element with matching custom data attribute

Tags: jquery

I have a list of elements with Custom Data Attributes. I need to be able to add a class to another element on click when the data attribute of a clicked element matches the data attribute of that element.

**HTML**

```
<div data-my-element="value1">click 1</div>  
<div data-my-element="another">click 2</div> 
<div data-my-element="oneMore">click 3</div> 

<section data-my-element="value1"></section>
<section data-my-element="another"></section>
<section data-my-element="oneMore"></section>
```

**JS**

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).val('data-my-element');
    $('section[data-my-element = '+myEm+']').addClass('clicked');
});
```

I think I'm doing something wrong.

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/wEgLp/)

Comment: Don't use `$(this).val('data-my-element')` instead use `$(this).data("my-element");`.  [jQuery Data()](http://api.jquery.com/data/).

Comment: You can use the data() method to get the value of the data attribute (or the attr method). Your call to val() is actually setting the value (even though val() would not work because that is used for input, select, and textarea)

Comment: You're also missing a few things in your script: `addClass('clicked');` and `});`

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('div').click(function() {
    var myEm = $(this).attr('data-my-element');
    //alert(myEm);
    $('section[data-my-element = '+myEm+']').addClass('clicked');
});
```

You are also missing:

`);` after `}` at the end of your code

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RqY4f/1/)**

Comment: This helped me a lot after hours of struggling!!

Answer (score 4):

Change:

```
 var myEm = $(this).val('data-my-element');
```

To:

```
 var myEm = $(this).data('my-element');
```

And if any of the data is being inserted or changed dynamically, you may consider using:

```
$('section').filter(function() { 
    return $(this).data('my-element') == myEm;
}).addClass('clicked');
```

Answer (score 0):

Change -

```
var myEm = $(this).val('data-my-element'); //doesn't have a value
```

to this -

```
var myEm = $(this).attr('data-my-element'); // returns the value of the custom attribute
```

or this

```
var myEm = $(this).data('my-element');
```